# How can I make sure no duplicate row is inserted

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I have a table in Oracle:

```
NAME     DATE      TIMEOFDAY    PAYMENT
SUBIR   10-08-12      DAY        10000 
SUBIR   10-08-12      NIGHT      12000
```

Now I want to make modification in the oracle table so that a single user cannot `pay` more than once in a particular day. For example, I cannot insert like:

```
NAME     DATE      TIMEOFDAY    PAYMENT
SUBIR   10-08-12      DAY        10000 
SUBIR   10-08-12      NIGHT      12000
SUBIR   10-08-12      DAY        14000
```

The 3rd row should not be inserted after the previous two records as there is already a payment that has been made in `day` on `10-08-12`. So how can I make this function in the oracle table?

**EDIT**- I guess I have to make `date` and `timeofday` compositely `unique`. Is it possible? The reason behind my such thinking is if I make both of them `unique` separately, users will not be allowed to enter a row with the same date for the second time but with different `timeofday`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(DATE, TIMEOFDAY)`:

```
ALTER TABLE tableX
  ADD CONSTRAINT unique_date_timeofday
    UNIQUE (DATE, TIMEOFDAY) ;
```

This constraint allows only unique combinations of the two fields.

Comment: I have to make `DATE` and `TIMEOFADAY` compositely `unique`. is it possible?

Comment: That's exactly what this constraint does, allows only unique combination of the two fields.

Answer (score 3):

1. If it's primary key:

`alter table YOUR_TABLE add constraint YOUR_TABLE_PK primary key (DATE, TIMEOFADAY);`

1. If you need only uniqueness

`create unique index YOUR_TABLE_IX1 on YOUR_TABLE_TAB (DATE, TIMEOFADAY);`